# Not able to switch pop up window having different action points

Tags: selenium

I am unable to switch pop-up using selenium on "http://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/UploadLargeFile" after clicking "Start Testing". It is not a frame, alert or window. I want to click on "Choose file" button. I believe it is not a window pop-up as it is present on DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It is present in DOM, you can locate the respective element and perform click action.

Code - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='file-input']")).click();

After execution of above code window file upload pop up will open.

Comment: I am not able to perform click operation on above element. Even I am not able perform any operation on "Upload file" popup.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait until upload popup appear then for file input use `send_keys()` to set the value

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[data-target="#upload-modal"]').click()
# wait until upload dialog appear
file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    lambda d: d.find_element_by_id('upload-modal').is_displayed()
)
file_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#file-input')
file_input.send_keys('/path/to/file.ext')
```

Comment: if solved please consider mark the answer as correct.